# Application_Error Event not working properly for HttpUnhandledException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling, global-asax

I added an event in `Global.asax` as below, to handle the exceptions (at application level) :-

`Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Dim exc As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
        Server.Transfer("ShowError.aspx")
        Server.ClearError()
    End Sub`

and in my `web.config` i added this :-

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"/>
```

Now whenever I am trying to access a page that does not exists in the application, my above code is working fine,
I am redirected to the `ShowError.aspx`.

But when there is a Telerik.Web.UI.GridException in one of my Pages(which is `HttpUnhandledException`), my `Application_Error` Event is firing but I am not redirected to the `ShowError.aspx`.

Could anyone help, what is the problem with GridException ??

Comment: first call the `Server.ClearError()` then do the redirect `Server.Transfer("ShowError.aspx")`. Change the order of last two statements and check.

Comment: @Ali Ashraf, It did'nt work !